# Maya: How to query the y value of a point on a mesh if I have the x and z coordinates?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am working in Maya and I have a curve and a "floor" mesh. At any point on the curve, I have x and z values (world space), giving me the top-down 2D location of the point. I want to project the curve down onto the floor to find the y value (i.e. height) of the floor at any point.

That is, given an x and z value, I want to query a mesh to give me the corresponding y value on the surface.
[image: curve and poly surface representing the floor]
[image]
[image]

These images were made using a poly surface but are mainly illustrative, for my purposes it doesn't matter too much whether the floor is a poly mesh or a poly/NURBS surface, so if one is more appropriate please say. (However it would be good to have an answer for all of these!)

I've tried to use the pointOnSurface, xform and pointPosition commands with no luck. I've also tried to use a closestPointOnSurface node, but I don't want the closest point in any direction, I specifically want a y value at an exact x and z point. I know that there is a y that satisfies these conditions as I am constructing the curve and mesh/surface myself.

I have the following code to get [x,z] coordinates at 50 sample points along the curve:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Returns x and z coordinates of points along path
def getPathPos():
    path = 'curve1'
    point_dist = 1.0/50
    path_pos = []

    for i in range(50):
        param = i * point_dist
        pos = cmds.pointOnCurve(path, parameter=param, turnOnPercentage=True, position=True)
        path_pos.append([pos[0], pos[2]])

    return path_pos
```

But then I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to use these points to query points on the mesh.

Happy with answers in Python or MEL.

Comment: can you include some of the code that you've tried?

Comment: Sorry for all the notifications, I tried to add code in a comment but the formatting was off. Will edit the post now.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why closestPointOnMesh wouldn't work, it is projecting your curve points onto the surface, is this code doesn't work for you :

```
def vec(p1, p2):
    return (p1[0]-p2[0], p1[1]-p2[1], p1[2]-p2[2])

curve, plane = cmds.ls(sl=True)
clst = cmds.createNode('closestPointOnMesh')
plane_sh = cmds.listRelatives(plane)[0]
cmds.connectAttr('{}.worldMesh[0]'.format(plane_sh),
                  '{}.inMesh'.format(clst))

cvs=cmds.ls('{}.ep[*]'.format(curve), fl=True)
cvs_orig_pos = [cmds.pointPosition(c) for c in cvs]
diff = []
for cv, pos in zip(cvs, cvs_orig_pos):
    cmds.setAttr('{}.inPosition'.format(clst), *pos)
    proj = cmds.getAttr('{}.position'.format(clst))[0]
    new_pos= [pos[0], proj[1], pos[2]]
    cmds.xform(cv, t=new_pos)

    value = vec(new_pos, pos)[1]
    if value > 0:
        print('above the floor')
    elif value<0:
        print('below the floor')
```

EDIT : i have seen your pcture with the floor thing so I've added a proc to verify this